# Performance gain implementing concatMap with foldl' for finite list?

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, fold

I read from [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') that `foldl'` is more efficient for long finite lists because of the strictness property. I am aware that it is not suitable for infinite list.

Thus, I am limiting the comparison only for long finite lists.

---

## concatMap

[`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#concatMap) is implemented using `foldr`, which gives it laziness. However, using it with long finite lists will build up a long unreduced chain according to the article.

```
concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]
concatMap f xs = build (\c n -> foldr (\x b -> foldr c b (f x)) n xs)
```

Thus I come up with the following implementation with use of `foldl'`.

```
concatMap' :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]
concatMap' f = reverse . foldl' (\acc x -> f x ++ acc) []
```

---

## Test it out

I have build the following two functions to test out the performance.

```
lastA = last . concatMap (: []) $ [1..10000]
lastB = last . concatMap' (: []) $ [1..10000]
```

However, I was shocked by the results.

```
lastA:
(0.23 secs, 184,071,944 bytes)
(0.24 secs, 184,074,376 bytes)
(0.24 secs, 184,071,048 bytes)
(0.24 secs, 184,074,376 bytes)
(0.25 secs, 184,075,216 bytes)

lastB:   
(0.81 secs, 224,075,080 bytes)
(0.76 secs, 224,074,504 bytes)
(0.78 secs, 224,072,888 bytes)
(0.84 secs, 224,073,736 bytes)
(0.79 secs, 224,074,064 bytes)
```

---

## Follow-up Questions

`concatMap` outcompetes my `concatMap'` in both time and memory. I wonder there are mistakes I made in my `concatMap'` implementation.

Thus, I doubt the articles for stating the goodness of `foldl'`.

1. Are there any black magic in `concatMap` to make it so efficient?
2. Is it true that `foldl'` is more efficient for long finite list?
3. Is it true that using `foldr` with long finite lists will build up a long unreduced chain and impact the performance?

Comment: Well you use `++` which runs in *O(n)* where *n* is the size of the left list... So you usually want to avoid that (since you are going to define a concat on a concat on a concat...)

Comment: @Willem Thank you for your timely response. For a `concatMap`, how can I avoid the `++`? Moreover, `f x` is of size 1 for the test case.

Comment: `foldl'` is good if you are building something in a nice strict data type from a seed using a strict function to update - like an`Int` starting with an `Int` seed using `(+)` to take the simplest example. If you are constructing a list or other lazy structure from a list, `foldr` will be much more natural.

Comment: Note your function is also incorrect - you should be reversing `f x` (try `concatMap (\x -> [-x,x]) [1,2,3]` and `concatMap' (\x -> [-x,x]) [1,2,3]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any black magic in concatMap to make it so efficient?

No, not really.

> Is it true that `foldl'` is more efficient for long finite list?

Not always. It depends on the folding function.

The point is, `foldl` and `foldl'` always have to scan the whole input list before producing the output. Instead, `foldr` does not always have to.

As an extreme case, consider

```
foldr (\x xs -> x) 0 [10..10000000]
```

which evaluates to `10` instantly -- only the first element of the list is evaluated. The reduction goes something like

```
foldr (\x xs -> x) 0 [10..10000000]
= foldr (\x xs -> x) 0 (10 : [11..10000000])
= (\x xs -> x) 10 (foldr (\x xs -> x) 0 [11..10000000])
= (\xs -> 10) (foldr (\x xs -> x) 0 [11..10000000])
= 10
```

and the recursive call is not evaluated thanks to laziness.

In general, when computing `foldr f a xs`, it is important to check whether `f y ys` is able to construct a part of the output *before* evaluating `ys`. For instance

```
foldr f [] xs
where f y ys = (2*y) : ys
```

produces a list cell `_ : _` before evaluating `2*y` and `ys`. This makes it an excellent candidate for `foldr`.

Again, we can define

```
map f xs = foldr (\y ys -> f y : ys) [] xs
```

which runs just fine. It consumes one element from `xs` and outputs the first output cell. Then it consumes the next element, outputs the next element, and so on. Using `foldl'` would not output anything until the whole list is processed, making the code quite inefficient.

Instead, if we wrote

```
sum xs = foldr (\y ys -> y+ys) 0 xs
```

then we do not output anything after the first element of `xs` is consumed. 
We build a long chain of thunks, wasting a lot of memory.
Here, `foldl'` would instead work in constant space.

> Is it true that using `foldr` with long finite lists will build up a long unreduced chain and impact the performance?

Not always. It strongly depends on how the output is consumed by the caller.

As a thumb rule, if the output is "atomic", meaning that the output consumer can not observe only a part of it (e.g. `Bool, Int, ...`) then it's better to use `foldl'`. If the output is "composed" of many independent values (list, trees, ...) probably `foldr` is a better choice, if `f` can produce its output step-by-step, in a "streaming" fashion.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. I have one more follow-up question. How can I avoid stack overflow when I `foldr` lazy structures?

Comment: @Gavin `foldr` works well when the function is not strict, otherwise it can result in a huge amount of thunks being created. So, foldr (\x y -> K e1 e2 .. en)` is OK, where `K` is a constructor. In the `map` example above, `K` was the list constructor `(:)`.